# Xamarin Forms WebView: Scroll to bottom of HTML Document

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, uwp

How can I scroll to the bottom in a WebView? I have already tried this, but it didn't work:

```
webView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code below in button click event.

```
   webview.Eval("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
```

Or you could do this via custom renderer. The html document would scroll to the bottom when you show it.

Android:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(ScrollWebView), typeof(ScrollWebViewRenderer))]
namespace App8.Droid
{
public class ScrollWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{
    public static ScrollWebView view = null;

    public ScrollWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Control.SetWebViewClient(new webviewClient(this, "window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);"));
    }
}
public class webviewClient : FormsWebViewClient
{
    string _javascript;
    public webviewClient(ScrollWebViewRenderer renderer, string javascript) : base(renderer)
    {
        _javascript = javascript;
    }
    public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        view.EvaluateJavascript(_javascript, null);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Unfourtunatly, it doesn't work :( But thanks for your attention

Comment: Could you provide more details for me to reproduce? I use the webview to load html string and it could be scrolled to bottom when i put the code in button click event.

Comment: @hyperpixel34 You could check my update to do it in custom renderer.